# Jquery Datatable search box align left

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, datatables

I am using backbone and jQuery datatable. By default search box of datatable comes on right side -
I want to align it to the left. Below is my code:

```
onDomRefresh: function(){
   $(this.el).find('table').dataTable({ "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',"bLengthChange": false });
}
```

[image]

But it's not working.

Answer (score 31):

You can use something like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(tableSelector).DataTable({
        "dom": '<"pull-left"f><"pull-right"l>tip'
    });
});
```

with

```
.pull-left{float:left!important;}
.pull-right{float:right!important;}
```

The result is this:
[image]

*(Note that Twitter Bootsrap is used on the screenshot, for additional table styling)*

More on DataTables DOM Manipulation can be found [here](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is not possible with sDom manipulation but you can adjust css rule for `.dataTables_filter` in `jquery.DataTables.css` or preferably override this rule in a custom css file:

```
#table_div_id.dataTables_filter {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

`table_div_id` is an id of container div used for initialization: `$('#table_div_id').dataTable()`

Comment: how this solution is aligning search box left?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dataTableId").DataTable({
        dom: '<"float-start"f><"#tableId"t>i<"#paginatorId"lp>',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#TableId').DataTable( "dom": '<"pull-left"f><"pull-right"l>tip' );        
});
```